# How can I get filename in tag <a download="123.xls">

Tags: android-webview

I can use URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype) to get filename, but how about this case?

```
<a herf="xxx" download="123.xls">Download file<a>
```

I want to get it in WebView.setDownloadListener, thanks for help.

```
binding.webView.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
   URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)
}
```